# Remove exact name from txt file

Tags: bash

I have the following code which removes certain lines from the file

```
ret=$(grep -m2 "$var" log.txt | tail -n1 ) 
 mv $var $ret                          
 grep -F -v $var log.txt > log.txt.tmp        
 mv log.txt.tmp log.txt
```

my log file looks like this

```
2.txt  
/home/etc/2.txt
```

basically the file name and its original location

I want to restore the file, and my program does do that, but I also want
to delete the name of the file and its location from log.txt file

now the above code works, but it removes all instances for example

it will remove 2.txt and the path which is fine, but if i had a file called 22.txt a completely different file it removes that as well. I need it to just remove 2.txt but appears to be removing line with "2.txt' in it.

is it possible to just remove 2.txt and since the directory has /2.txt in it remove that entire line as well?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. You just wrote a second question which is very similar to your first. Maybe you could consider explaining your full problem you are trying to solve and we might help. At the current rate, you will ask several questions building on the previous while in the end the solution to your problem might be a simple command.

Comment: this is a different question actually the original question was solved. I just need to rework the grep to not incldue all files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in you `log.txt` file, you want to :

- match `2.txt` on a single line
- match `2.txt` preceded by some path.

You can do this in grep:

```
# match all but lines beginning with $var, so 2.txt
grep -F -v "^$var" log.txt > log.txt.tmp        

# match all but lines containing "/$var", so "/2.txt"
grep -F -v "/$var" log.txt.tmp > log.txt
```